# How does the number $3$ help in this (probably Cauchy-based) inequality?

Tags: inequality, summation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> Given $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=3$. Prove that
>   $$\dfrac{a^2+bc}{b+ca}+\dfrac{b^2+ca}{c+ab}+\dfrac{c^2+ab}{a+bc}\ge3$$

**Attempt:**

Using Cauchy inequality $(a+b\ge2\sqrt{ab})$:

$\dfrac{a^2}{b+ca}+b+ca\ge 2\sqrt{a^2}=2a$

$\dfrac{b^2}{c+ab}+c+ab\ge 2\sqrt{b^2}=2b$

$\dfrac{c^2}{a+bc}+a+bc\ge 2\sqrt{c^2}=2c$

Adding all the inequalities, we have:

$\dfrac{a^2}{b+ca}+\dfrac{b^2}{c+ab}+\dfrac{c^2}{a+bc}+ab+bc+ca+a+b+c\ge2(a+b+c)$

$\Rightarrow\dfrac{a^2}{b+ca}+\dfrac{b^2}{c+ab}+\dfrac{c^2}{a+bc}+ab+bc+ca\ge 3$, but I don't see how that's relevant and I'm stuck here.

Comment: **Hint**: Use this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896384/x-y-z-0-if-xyz-geq-xy-yz-zx-prove-that-xyz-geq-3xyz

Answer (score 1):

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+bc}{b+ca}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a^2+bc)^2}{(a^2+bc)(b+ca)}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+bc)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+bc)(b+ca)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+ab)\right)^2\geq3\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+bc)(b+ca)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4+2a^2b^2+a^2b^2+2a^2bc+2a^3b+2a^3c+2a^2bc)\geq$$
$$\geq3\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^3c+a^2b+a^2bc)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4+2a^3b+2a^3c+3a^2b^2+4a^2bc-2a^3b-2a^2b^2-2a^2bc-3a^3c-3a^2bc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4-a^3c+a^2b^2-a^2bc)\geq0,$$
which is true by Rearrangement and AM-GM.